# How to change text color based on checkbox value - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to change the text color if the checkbox is selected but I am stuck. I have a function called `getTextColor` that should define which color should be used depending on the text.

In that case, when the checkbox is selected, it should check if the text has an 'A' in it and, if so, apply the blue color. How to achieve this?

Here is how I am trying to build it:

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  bool? dominant_A = false;

  Color getTextColor(String text) {
    var TheRightColor = Colors.black;

    if (text == 'AABB' || text == 'AaBb') {
      TheRightColor = Colors.blueAccent;
    } 

    return TheRightColor;
  }

  // Here is the structure of the checkbox
  void _onDominant_A(bool? newValue) => setState(() {
        dominant_A = newValue;

        if (dominant_A ?? true) {
          // Here should be the logic that applies the blue color to 'AABB' and 'AaBb' (both has an 'A').

        } 
      });
```

Here is how it's called later:

```
         TextSpan(
                  text: widget.result + '  ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: object.getTextColor(widget.result), // The result is the text
                    height: 2.5,
                    letterSpacing: 0.7,
                  )),
```

**Additional information:** I'm not sure if the function `getTextColor` needs to exist. I just put it there because I don't know how to call it later like I did in the second code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a variable for storing the right color, try assesing the right color in `getTextColor()` and return that to the style property of your text. This way the text color will always be recomputed everytime you `setState((){})`

Below is an implementation of the same. See if it helps.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String text = "AABB";

    Color getTextColor(String textToBeAssesed) {
      if (isChecked) {
        //Logic to be checked if checkbox is clicked
        if (text == 'AABB' || text == 'AaBb') {
          return Colors.blueAccent;
        } else {
          return Colors.black;
        }
      } else {
        //Logic to be checked if checkbox is unticked
        return Colors.black;
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Checkbox(
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  isChecked = !isChecked;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: getTextColor(text)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is with the `Text()` at the end of your code. In my case, this `Text()` is in another class that displays the `widget.result` (the text itself). How could I access it?

Comment: If your `Text()` lies in a child class, the you can always pass `getTextColor()` to the child class as an argument since dart treats all functions as first class data objects.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I believe you can use setState for this:

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  bool? dominant_A = false;
  Color textSpanColor = Color(0xFFEFEFEF); //your textspan default color here

  checkText(String text){
      if (dominant_A) {
          setState(() { textSpanColor = getColor(); });
      }
  }

  Color getColor() {
      Color color = Colors.black;

      if (text == 'AABB' || text == 'AaBb') {
          color = Colors.blueAccent;
      }
  
      return color;
  }
```

Your textspan:

```
TextSpan(
    text: widget.result + '  ',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: textSpanColor,
        height: 2.5,
        letterSpacing: 0.7,
    ),
),
```

Here you will pass the color when a checkbox is selected using onChanged:

```
Checkbox(
  ...
  value: dominant_A,
  onChanged: (bool? value) {
      setState(() {
         dominant_A = value!;
      });
      checkText(widget.result);
  },
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am testing it, but it seems that the `getColor()` is requiring a return statement at the end of it. What should I put there?

Comment: I updated, try again

Comment: In `checkText(widget.result)` it appears this error: `The getter 'result' isn't defined for the type 'MainScreen'`.

Comment: Só agora percebi que você também é brasileiro!

Comment: Haha, fica mais fácil! você definiu `result` na sua classe? Exemplo: `const MainScreen({Key? key, required this.result}) : super(key: key); final String result;`

Comment: Eu fiz isso em outra classe, porque tenho que fazer esse `result` aparecer na próxima tela aí criei uma classe pra próxima tela e defini esse `result`

Comment: O erro que você descreveu acima significa que o `result` não está definido para MainScreen. De onde você está recebendo o `result`?

Comment: O `TextSpan` na verdade está dentro de outra classe (a mesma classe da próxima página que mencionei acima). Aí eu estava conseguindo acessar o `result` por causa disso. Ele estava definido lá. Eu teria que defini-lo novamente na MainScreen?

Comment: Eu não vejo outra saída a não ser definir o `return` na mesma classe que o `TextSpan`, por que se não for definido, a função não funciona. Desculpe, sou leigo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237189/discussion-between-bilbo-bo-and-jesse-lopes-pereira).

Comment: Vou estar com o chat aberto, aí quando for voltar é só dar um toque por lá :D

Comment: Oie Jessé @JesseLopesPereira! Posso te chamar num bate-papo privado? Queria tirar uma dúvida sobre uma parte de meu projeto. :D